# How to detect if a device is an iPad?

Tags: css

Is it possible to detect whether a browser is running on iOS (I want to know if the device is an iPad) by using feature detect with Modernizr. Like it adds lt-ie8 class for IE8. I want to know what it sticks to `<html>` class if the device is an iPad.
I just want to add css classes exclusively for iPad.

Comment: You can do so relying on screen resolution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839809/detect-iphone-ipad-purely-by-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to detect the \*type of mobile device\* via javascript or HTTP Headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158369/possible-to-detect-the-type-of-mobile-device-via-javascript-or-http-headers)

Comment: $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Modernizer to declare a class on the body or html tag when a person is viewing a certain browser.

From there you can declare those classes within your stylesheet.

https://modernizr.com/docs#using-modernizr-with-css

Answer (score 0):

via the user-agent header.

Copied from google search, I searched for user-agent ipad.

```
User-Agent String   Apple Product   iOS Version Build
Apple-iPad1C1/807.4 iPad    4.3.1   8G4 Mar 25, 2011
Apple-iPad1C1/808.7 iPad    4.3.2   8H7 Apr 14, 2011
Apple-iPad1C1/810.3 iPad    4.3.3   8J3 May 4, 2011
Apple-iPad1C1/811.2 iPad    4.3.4   8K2 Jul 15, 2011
```

Basically you should search for Apple-Ipad* in the user-agent header.